# Selenium webdrivers not responding properly to method calls in Django

Tags: django, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

Hey wonderful people of stackoverflow,

when I attempt to run this code:

```
from selenium import webdriver


browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get("http://localhost:8000")

assert 'Django' in browser.title
```

Chrome opens however does not show http://localhost:8000 in the address, instead shows:
data:,
and this below in one of those warning yellow warning bars:
"Unsupportedd command-line flag: --ignore-certificate-errors."

Any thoughts? I tried adding "--test-type" to the launch settings of chromedriver but it didn't seem to work. I'm worried moving forward I won't be able to properly use many elements of the browser for testing, also I tried to install firefox to no avail. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: my gut feeling is that there is a version mismatch somewhere. probably between chromedriver and selenium

Answer (score 1):

You can get up-to-date version of `chromdriver` from [here](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.27/) or use following code:

```
from selenium import webdriver

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["ignore-certificate-errors"])
browser = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
browser.get("http://localhost:8000")

assert 'Django' in browser.title
```

Comment: This is probably right, because version mismatches are indeed the cause of this problem

Comment: unfortunately that does not solve my original issue nor does it remove the flag.

Comment: Is this because I am using chrome as my primary browser perhaps ? Sorry for the double response. Just trying to be as thorough as possible so I can actually get started on developing my ideas. With your code I also get an error in socket.py                 return self._sock.recv_into(b) I am running selenium 3.0.2 and I don't know how to check what version of chrome I have I can't seem to import it in the python terminal. Thank you for your patience/ any ideas would be appreciated!

Comment: You can simply execute `chromedriver` from `cmd`/`Terminal` to check version. Also check whether you use last version of `Chrome`. This issue couldn't be caused by default browser name